# NETLOGO- How to print values of variables in order of their label

Tags: sorting, netlogo, agent

I'm very new to Netlogo. I have a variable (U) for my breed (consumers) and I want to show them sorted by their label not randomly i.e.( I want it to print U of agent 0 then U of agent 1 etc.) Can someone please help me?

Thank You!
Elham

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sort the agent set based on the who to create an ordered list. Then iterate on the resulting list using a for loop.

```
foreach sort turtles
  [ the-turtle -> ask the-turtle [ show U ] ]
```

Comment: You don't need `sort-on [who] turtles`: just `sort turtles` is sufficient, since [`sort`](https://ccl.northwestern.edu/netlogo/docs/dictionary.html#sort) already sorts by `who` number.